# Vue.js bind with es6 template string

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, template-strings

Why can't I use es6 template-string with vue.js `v-bind:style`

this works:

```
<div :style="{transform:'translate('+x+'px,'+y+'px)'}">
```

but this silently fail:

```
<div :style="{transform:`translate(${x}px,${y}px)`}">
```

(I'm of course aware with es6 browser compatibility an use browser supporting template string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

template string was not supported by vue.js, I open [an issues](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2364), it will be [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/commit/142046fad4aaf75efa1e362a258094bb3fbcd8c8)